# Xcode Editor Messing Up

Tags: xcode, editor

I'm having some trouble with Xcode.  A lot of times I'll just be typing code in, and then something will suddenly happen that screws up how the text displays on the page.  Sometimes it will cut off the first characters of some lines.  Other times, especially when I'm typing near the bottom (I notice it occurs when it tries to do some autocomplete but I type over it) it will not display the bottom text (like the @end) and won't take anymore text input properly.

If I quit and restart, the file displays properly again until it happens another time.  Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?  I just tried reinstalling Xcode, but even after doing that I still have the same problem.

This problem is really annoying because I often have to quit and restart constantly, and sometimes it's scary because it looks like I've lost the code that I've typed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- make sure you're using the latest version of Xcode (3.2.1)
- rather than quit and restart, try just saving and closing the file's window and then re-open it

Answer (score 0):

The real solution to this problem is close quick help.
Turns out "Quick Help" causes alot of issues with codesense.
If you close it your troubles are gone. It will work fine once you reopen it... for a while. Then it will begin messing up again.

I used to leave quick help up 24/7 so this happened frequently. I have seen other reports of this being the cause on a few other sites. Aven on this very same site. (stackoverflow)